# Why this simple LINQ to SQL update query is not working?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, linq, linq-to-sql

I'm using VS 2010, MS SQL Server 2008, WPF 4

```
PalQuotationDataContext _palQuotationDataContext = new PalQuotationDataContext(); 
public void UpdateItemInformation(EItemInformation anItemInformation)
{
     var itemInformation = _palQuotationDataContext.ITEMs.Single(item =>
                                      item.IM_ID == anItemInformation.Id);
     itemInformation.IM_NAME = anItemInformation.Name;
     itemInformation.IM_DESCRIPTION = anItemInformation.Description;
     itemInformation.IM_BRAND = anItemInformation.Brand;
     itemInformation.IM_ORIGIN = anItemInformation.Origin;
     itemInformation.IM_ACESS_BY = anItemInformation.AccessBy;

     _palQuotationDataContext.SubmitChanges();
}
```

Comment: Does your table have a primary key?

Comment: What's the error? It would be much easier to solve the problem if we knew what is wrong....

Comment: @ keyboardP: Thanks. You solve my problem.

Comment: @  Jakub Konecki: It wasn't showing any error, just the values wasn't updating. And I solved my problem. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your table needs a `primary key`.